# Group private messages in Django by users

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have built a private messaging system for registered users in Django, and I have a small issue. I cannot think of a way to group the messages by users.

The image below shows the messages between two users. This is the conversation as seen by the user **karolann**. You can see that it does not group the messages correctly. The sentences **"Hello Susan"** and **"Those two modules are quite challenging"** should come after the last sentence - **"Text me when you online."**.

Right now, the messages are grouped by the sender. If I group them by the receiver, it still does not work properly. It would need something that is common for both like a conversation id or something.

So my question is: How do I create conversations? I want all the messages between two users to be in the same place.

[image]

My models.py is as follows:
[image]

My views.py is as follows:
[image]

And lastly, my template:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply multiple filters for both sender and receiver together from both users' side and then join them.
Using dictsort and regroup will not work in such a case.

To get all messages in a user/other_user conversation, you need:

```
Message.objects.filter(sender=user.profile, reciever=other_user.profile)|Message.objects.filter(receiver=user.profile, sender=other_user.profile)
```

(Note | operator can be used for union)

You shall create these queries for each conversation in the view and pass a list of these queries in the template context.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @philoj. So should I iterate over all the users registered? I don't quite get it. In my views, I can get the user I want (user.profile) but not sure about the other one - other_user.profile.

Comment: Iterate over all other users who have messaged the current user atleast once.

Comment: I mean iterate over all other users who have messaged the current user or recieved a message from him. Again you will have to join two queries for this

Comment: I will accept your answer as it's a reasonable solution, even though it did not work in my case. Thank you, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

For whoever tries to do this in Django, I recommend this solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43697388/10036828.

This is the only way I could make it work.