# Django conversation categories for messages with ManyToMany

Tags: python, django, model, many-to-many

I am making a kind of social network in Django. This explains basically what I'm doing:

[Django - Private messaging conversation view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43696074/django-private-messaging-conversation-view)

The conversations are exclusively between two people, not more. I have a conversation model because when they to their messages, I want the user to have a list of the other users that they have messages with.

Here is the relevant view:

```
def writemessage(request, id):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(id=id)
    context = {
        'profile': profile,
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sender = request.user
        receiver = profile.user
        content = request.POST['content']
        timestamp = datetime.now()
        print(sender, receiver, content, timestamp)
        record = Message(sender=sender, receiver=receiver, content=content, timestamp=timestamp)
        record.save()
        senderprofile = Profile.objects.get(user=sender)
        receiverprofile = Profile.objects.get(user=receiver)
        record.conversation.add(senderprofile)
        record.conversation.add(receiverprofile)
        print(senderprofile, receiverprofile)
        return redirect('messagespage')
    return render(request, 'thecode/writemessage.html', context)
```

Here are my models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    skillstolearn = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    skillstoteach = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Conversation(models.Model):
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.participants

class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sender')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='receiver')
    content = models.TextField()
    conversation = models.ForeignKey(Conversation, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sender.username + ' to ' + self.receiver.username
```

I know about some documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/

I've tried to understand the documentation and also posts on here but am a little bit stuck.

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add' = the error messages that I get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Message` object's `conversation` field is `None` by default, and your view function doesn't set `conversation` before trying to read it. You need to figure out what `Conversation` this message belongs in, and then set it when you construct the `Message`:

```python
record = Message(conversation=???, sender=sender, receiver=receiver, content=content, timestamp=timestamp)
        record.save()
```

**How do you know which conversation a `User` is in?**

A few code review notes:

- The `related_name` arguments for your `ForeignKey` fields indicate the name of the field on the `User` model that refers *back* to the `Message` model, not the other way around. Therefore, instead of `sender` and `receiver`, they should be `messages_sent` and `messages_received`. Please update your original posting to improve the clarity.

  ```python
  # Example of accessing sent and received messages from a User model:
  user.messages_sent
  user.messages_received
  ```